# resizing a UIImage without loading it entirely into memory?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiimage

I'm developing an application where a user could potentially try and load very very large images. These images are first displayed as thumbnails in a table view. My original code would crash on large images, so I'm rewriting it to first download the image directly to disk.

Is there a known way to resize an image on disk without entirely loading it into memory via `UIImage`? I'm currently trying to resize using the categories on `UIImage` as detailed [here](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/), but my app crashes on attempting to thumbnail a very large image (like, for example, [this](http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2003-28-a-full_jpg.jpg) - warning, huge image).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You should take a look at CGImageSource in ImageIO.framework, but it is only available since iOS 4.0.

Quick example :

```
-(UIImage*)resizeImageToMaxSize:(CGFloat)max path:(NSString*)path
{
    CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path], NULL);
    if (!imageSource)
        return nil;

    CFDictionaryRef options = (CFDictionaryRef)[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        (id)kCFBooleanTrue, (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform,
        (id)kCFBooleanTrue, (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageIfAbsent,
        (id)@(max),
        (id)kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize,
        nil];
    CGImageRef imgRef = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, options);

    UIImage* scaled = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgRef];

    CGImageRelease(imgRef);
    CFRelease(imageSource);

    return scaled;
}
```

Comment: how can I add a seperated value for height and width? are this retina values? Do I have to choose 2048 or 1024 for a retina ipad screen?

Comment: You should do x*[UIScreen mainScreen].scale

Comment: What is @max here?

Comment: @Reza.Ab - You probably long since figured it out, but it’s the `kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize` value, i.e., the “maximum width and height in pixels of a thumbnail.” Nyx0uf is passing this `max` value as a parameter to the method. And the `@(...)` is just “[boxing](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#boxed-expressions)” this into a `NSNumber`. It’s basically syntactic sugar for converting this `CGFloat` into a `NSNumber`. (You can’t just insert primitive numeric types into a dictionary, but rather you have to wrap them in a `NSNumber` object.)

Answer (score 3):

According to this session, [iOS Memory Deep Dive](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/416/), we had better use `ImageIO` to downscale images.

The bad of using `UIImage` downscale images.

- Will decompress original image into memory
- Internal coordinate space transforms are expensive

Use `ImageIO`

- ImageIO can read image sizes and metadata information without dirtying memory.
- ImageIO can resize images at cost of resized image only.

About Image in memory

- Memory use is related to the dimensions of the images, not the file size.
- `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` always uses `SRGB` rendering-format, which use 4 bytes per pixel.
- A image have `load -> decode -> render` 3 phases.
- `UIImage` is expensive for sizing and to resizing

For the following image, if you use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`
we only need 590KB to load a image, while we need
`2048 pixels x 1536 pixels x 4 bytes per pixel` = 10MB when decoding 
[image]

while `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`, introduced in iOS 10, will automatically pick the best graphic format in iOS12. It means, you may save 75% of memory by replacing `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` with `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` if you don't need SRGB.

This is my article about [iOS images in memory](https://suelan.github.io/2020/05/03/iOS-images-in-memory/)

```swift
func resize(url: NSURL, maxPixelSize: Int) -> CGImage? {
    let imgSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url, nil)
    guard let imageSource = imgSource else {
        return nil
    }

    var scaledImage: CGImage?
    let options: [NSString: Any] = [
            // The maximum width and height in pixels of a thumbnail.
            kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: maxPixelSize,
            kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways: true,
            // Should include kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: true in the options dictionary. Otherwise, the image result will appear rotated when an image is taken from camera in the portrait orientation.
            kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: true
    ]
    scaledImage = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, options as CFDictionary)

    return scaledImage
}


let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"large_leaves_70mp", ofType: "jpg")

let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath ?? "")

let image = resize(url: url, maxPixelSize: 600)
```

or

```
// Downsampling large images for display at smaller size
func downsample(imageAt imageURL: URL, to pointSize: CGSize, scale: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    let imageSourceOptions = [kCGImageSourceShouldCache: false] as CFDictionary
    let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(imageURL as CFURL, imageSourceOptions)!
    let maxDimensionInPixels = max(pointSize.width, pointSize.height) * scale
    let downsampleOptions =
        [kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways: true,
        kCGImageSourceShouldCacheImmediately: true,
        // Should include kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: true in the options dictionary. Otherwise, the image result will appear rotated when an image is taken from camera in the portrait orientation.
        kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: true,
        kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: maxDimensionInPixels] as CFDictionary
    let downsampledImage =
        CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, downsampleOptions)!
    return UIImage(cgImage: downsampledImage)
}
```