# Resizing UIImage in UIImageView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview

I'm trying to create a UIPickerView with some images in it, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the images to fit in the view (right now they're too large and are overlapping each other).

I'm trying to use a function to resize each image when it's drawn, but I'm getting errors when the function is called, although the program compiles and runs fine (with the exception of the image not resizing). The resizing function and initialization functions are:

```
-(UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image width:(int)width height:(int)height {
    NSLog(@"resizing");
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageRef);
    
    //if (alphaInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone)
    alphaInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;
    
    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), 
                                                4 * width, CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef), alphaInfo);
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];
    
    CGContextRelease(bitmap);
    CGImageRelease(ref);
    
    return result;  
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIImage *h1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"h1.png"];
    
    h1 = [self resizeImage:h1 width:50 height: 50];
    
    UIImageView *h1View = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:h1];
        
    NSArray *imageViewArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                h1View, nil];
    
    NSString *fieldName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"column1"];
    [self setValue:imageViewArray forKey:fieldName];
    [fieldName release];
    [imageViewArray release];
        
    [h1View release];
}
```

Console Output:

> TabTemplate[29322:207] resizing
>
> TabTemplate[29322] : CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported colorspace
>
> TabTemplate[29322] : CGContextDrawImage: invalid context
>
> TabTemplate[29322] : CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context

I can't figure out what's going wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check if the value returned by CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef) is one of the values accepted by CGBitmapContextCreate?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't require to resize your `UIImage` if you use the `contentMode` property of `UIImageView`.

```
    myImageView.contentMode  = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Or if you still want to resize your UIImage, Have look at below SO post.

[resizing a UIImage without loading it entirely into memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860215/resizing-a-uiimage-without-loading-it-entirely-into-memory)

[UIImage: Resize, then Crop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603907/uiimage-resize-then-crop)

Answer (score 14):

Use below to scale the image using aspect ratio, then clip the image to imageview's bounds.

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. `clipsToBounds` was what I was missing - huge help!

Comment: This will correctly fill the view with the image while keeping its aspect ratio but hides what doesn't fit in the area.

Answer (score 0):

In case of swift

```
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];
    [image drawInRect: destinationRect];
    UIImage *thumbnail = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,nil,nil,nil);
```