# Resize image in UITabBarItem programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbaritem

I have this code who, put an image inside a barItem:

```
frist.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];
```

It works perfectly, but the image does not appear, because the image have 256x256 pixels, I've heard that the image must have a 30x30 pixels, but I don't wanna to change resolution manually, I want to change this per code, is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];

[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];

frist.tabBarItem.image = image;
```

Comment: One question, if i do this, the ios is reading a image 256x256 and rezise this for 30x30, but this consume more memory no?

Comment: This will consume more memory, since it is loading the UIImage and then resizing it. Another way is to look at ImageIO.framework.

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860215/resizing-a-uiimage-without-loading-it-entirely-into-memory

Answer (score 0):

```
let moreVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MoreVC")
moreVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "More", image: UIImage(named: "fifth"), tag: 5)
moreVC.tabBarItem.imageInsets.top = 7
moreVC.tabBarItem.imageInsets.bottom = 7
```

Comment: Can you provide some context on why this code snippet solves the sizing problem? TIA.