# Memory increasing when loading image on image view?

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimageview

I am loading image from url on a image-view. If the resolution of the image is 4000 * 2400 ,size of image is 1.6MB then when I load image. Memory increase upto 30MB just for image load. But if size is less than 10 KB then size does not increase. I know I must use small image for loading as thumb image but just for learning I want to know this.

I am using below code to load image

```
self.imgStore.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "placeholder"), options: nil, progressBlock: { (val, val1) in        }) { (image, error, cache, url) in
    DILog.print(items: "image recived")
}
```

1. Why memory size increase upto 30 MB when image size is just 1.5 Mb ?
2. How can I handle if image from server is large but memory in app should not increase. ?

Answer (score 1):

1.5MB is compressed size. PNG's are decompressed in memory and it consume memory on pixel basis (RGBA). So the the size will be `4000 * 2400 * 4 ~= 38MB`

If your image are too big and you can't change the resolution.

1. Download the image and save directly on the disk.
2. Resize the image before loading it in memory. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860215/resizing-a-uiimage-without-loading-it-entirely-into-memory) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Can you tell me how can i reduce the size of image so that size does not increase ?

Comment: By reducing the resolution from `4000 * 2400` to what's required in your app. Or if you can't do that see my edited answer.

Comment: Image in memory size is directly proportional to image resolution.